# Setting form option values with Javascript (applescript UI workflow) chosen.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have an Applescript that logs me into bufferapp.com.
I want it to also set the times for my scheduled posts.
I can get it to this page, but then I'm stuck.
Since the class is "chzn-select", I can't get by class name and set value that way.
I'm an absolute novice, so please forgive my ignorance.

Here is the html (direct link - http://cl.ly/image/2G283Z1T2E0F/Screenshot_2014-04-21_17_06_20.png) for the page showing one of the drop-downs.

```
<form>
    <p>Post at <span class="timescount">this time</span> <strong class="name">Every Day</strong> : </p>
    <ol id="schedule-times">
        <li data-index="0">
            <i class="ss-icon">⏲</i>
            <select name="hour" class="chzn-select" ,="" style="width: 60px">
                <option value="01">01</option>
                <option value="02">02</option>
                <option value="03">03</option>
```

Applescript

```
tell application "Safari"
do JavaScript " $('.chzn-select option:selected').val('03');"  in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

The following code changed the values (finally), but I'm not sure how or why.

```
tell application "Safari"
 do JavaScript " $('select option:nth-child(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
 $('select option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
 $('select option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
 $('select').trigger('liszt:updated');" in current tab of window 1
end tell
```

When I run this, all of my "hour" dropdowns change to '3' and all of the "minute" dropdowns change to '2'

Comment: So do you want to manually set the value of the selected option each time you make a selection? Do you always want the value to be '03'? The code you have there won't work either way because the class name should be simply `'chzn-select'`, and you cannot use CSS selectors (i.e., `:selected`) in plain JavaScript. Try `"$('.chzn-select option:selected').val('whateverValueYouWant');"`

Comment: Still doesn't change any form values... I'm ok with it being '03' each time right now. I just want to see the basic function work. How does the function know which "<li data-index=..." to select? Or even which dropdown "name"? There are 3 (hour/minute/ampm) identically named dropdowns per li and any number of li's that I choose to add.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of selected options in jQuery by adding a value attribute to the HTML:

```
<option value="some-value">
```

And the jQuery to get that value would be:

```
$('select option:selected').val();
```

Or you can SET the value in very much the same way. The HTML:

```
<option value="">
```

The jQuery to SET the value:

```
$('select option:selected').val('some-value');
```

Hope that helps.

UPDATE** I don't know anything about Applescript, but here is some updated HTML and JavaScript you can use to get either the value of the selected option, get the text of the selected option, or set the value of the selected option:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <select id="sel" class="chzn-select">
            <option>Please Select</option>
            <option value="a">First Choice</option>
            <option value="b">Second Choice</option>
            <option value="c">Third Choice</option>
            <option value="d">Fourth Choice</option>
        </select>
        <input id="valueButton" type="button" value="GET VALUE">
        <input id="textButton" type="button" value="GET TEXT">
        <input id="setValue" type="button" value="SET VALUE">
    </form>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('valueButton').onclick = function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("sel");
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(val);
}

document.getElementById('textButton').onclick = function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("sel");
    var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(text);
}

document.getElementById('setValue').onclick = function(){
    var e = document.getElementById('sel');
    var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
    sel.value = "03";
    alert(sel.value);
}
```

A fiddle to show that the JS works (if these functions do not work for you in your own project it means that you've likely got the syntax wrong, or that there is some compatibility issue with Applescript): http://jsfiddle.net/YPfcr/

You can see that the SET VALUE button is working by making a choice, clicking "GET VALUE", then clicking "SET VALUE" on that same selection, then clicking "GET VALUE" again. You'll see that it has changed to "03".

If you can't get this to work for you, it's probably best ask a new question specific to Applescript.

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps. Can you please explain how I would apply what you've described into my workflow described above?

Comment: There was a mistake in the "general" example. Here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/77nBz/2/

Comment: it does help.. its closer, but this code still requires that I actually select something. I want to tell it an exact value to be set to, regardless of what its currently set to.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. I'll give it another crack if you can be a lot more specific about what you're trying to do. Each option can only have one value, so it's either going to be what you declare it to be in your HTML, or it's going to be what you declare it to be with JavaScript. If you have in your HTML `value="1"` and then you change that with JS to `someOtherValue`, the new value will be the only value until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Sure thing.. Basically, I have an Applescript workflow that I am using to log me into Bufferapp.com. I can get the javascript to login, go to the right page and add posting times, but I cannot set the times. Thats all I want it to do.. just fill out the form with the desired time. My suspicion is the plugin Chosen (used to create the dropdowns) is making this more difficult than with normal select menus.

Comment: Well, the problem is certainly in your script, so maybe update your question with the script you're using.

Comment: Thx.. I updated the code... I used a similar line to input text into an empty text field on the same page.